# renderEcharts4r tooltip number and percentage

Tags: r, shiny, charts

I have an R shiny application and I am wanting to add both the % and number of completers to the tooltip.

This is the code so far:

```
output$comp_per <- renderEcharts4r({
        req(base_input$location)
        # browser()
        req(input$secondvar)
        var_name <- input$secondvar
        data_all() %>%
          filter(completed == "Y") %>%  
          count(location, !!sym(var_name)) %>% 
          group_by(location) %>% 
          summarise(n2 = sum(n)) -> temp
    
      
    # browser()
    data_all() %>%
      filter(completed == "Y") %>%  
      count(location, !!sym(var_name)) %>%
      left_join(temp) %>% 
      mutate(n = 100*n/n2) %>%
      mutate(n = round(n, 1)) %>%
      group_by(!!sym(var_name)) %>% 
      e_charts(location) %>%
      e_bar(n, legend = TRUE, stack = "grp") %>%
      e_axis(axisLabel = list(interval = 0, rotate = 45)) %>%
      e_y_axis(max = 100) %>% 
      e_format_y_axis(suffix = "%") %>% 
      e_grid(containLabel = TRUE) %>%
      # e_grid(containLabel = TRUE) %>% 
      e_tooltip(
        trigger = "axis",
        valueFormatter = htmlwidgets::JS("(value) =>'% of Completers: ' + Number(value).toFixed(2)"))
  })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsPR4.png)

This is only displaying the % and not both the % and number completed.

Comment: I would try curly braces: `(value) =>{'% of Completers: ' + Number(value).toFixed(2)}` (absolutely not sure)